# How to manipulate a movieclip inside another movieclip independently

Tags: actionscript-3

So, I am trying to make a flash game with a bomber plane with a rear-gunner.  I have made the plane a movieclip and, inside that, have the gunner movieclip.  I am trying to use key controls to move the plane and have the gunner follow the mouse cursor.  I am not certain if there is a way to make the gunner movieclip stay attached to the plane and move independently.  Right now the only thing that works is instantiating a gunner and adding it to the frame, but I am having problems keeping it in the right location while the plane moves.

Comment: Well, I have a few classes at the moment.  I can upload them all if you would like.  But, I am mostly just trying to find out how to mess with a movieclip that is a part of another movieclip i.e. make it rotate on its own while the plane rotates.

Comment: Or also, is there a way to make a reference point on a movieclip that I can get the location of.  Not the Registration point thing.  Because if I try and have the gunner offset from the center, the math gets all weird when the plane starts to rotate for the gun to stay in the same place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can refer to a movieclip in another movieclip by naming it

Picture example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/weNeF.png

then you can refer to it in your actionscipt by writing`yourPlane_mc.gun` Example: `yourPlane_mc.gun.rotation = mouseAngleToPlane`

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!  Apparently I am awful at phrasing my question correctly in Google because I could not find the answer.  My next question is, can I still make the gun have its own class?  I tried leaving it, but as I don't need to pass in x, y position or add it to the stage the constructor would just be empty.  And if I try to leave it empty I get "Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference."

Comment: yes, but then you will have to remove it from the plane and place it with actionscip like `plane_mc.addChild(gun)`

Comment: also, can you show me the lines at which it gives the null object reference?

Comment: Never mind, I figured out a better way to do it.  Instead I created a point on the plane for the gun and named it the way you showed me.  Then I grab that point's x and y and send it to the gun to update its location.  Thank you again for your help!